# Meteor Methods and CoffeeScript

Tags: methods, meteor, coffeescript

For some reason, I can't get the method on the server to execute.  I don't see the "Timer has started" console.log on the server, and the "foo" does not return.  What am I missing?

Please see code:

```
if Meteor.isClient
    console.log "client is alive and well."
    Session.setDefault("duration", 1200000)
    Session.setDefault("timeRemaining", 1200000)

    Template.timer.helpers
        duration: () ->
            Session.get("duration")

        timeRemaining: () ->
            Session.get("timeRemaining")

    Template.timer.events
        'click #start': () ->
            console.log "Started."
            Meteor.call("startTimer", (error, result) ->
                console.log "Result is #{result}")  

        'click #pause': () ->
            console.log "Paused."
            Meteor.call("pauseTimer", (error, result) ->
                console.log "Result is #{result}")  

        'click #cancel': () ->
            console.log "Cancelled."
            Meteor.call("cancelTimer", (error, result) ->
                console.log "Result is #{result}")      

if Meteor.isServer
    Meteor.startup () ->
        console.log "Server is alive."

    Meteor.methods
        startTimer: () ->
            console.log "Timer has started."
            "foo"
```

Comment: what happens if you go to your browser console and type Meteor.call("startTimer")

Comment: Hi @KeithNicholas, it comes back as "undefined".

Comment: thats normal. what does it say on your server console?

Comment: Nothing shows on the server console except "server is alive."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine. Are you sure you have your element with id 'start' in a template called timer?

I copy and pasted your code into a Meteorpad with minimal HTML and it works:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/d9KLWPj6SZPDxr4Et/SO-Answer

Click the Test button and you should see Timer has started in the black console (output fromserver) and Result is foo if you check your browser's console

Do you even get 'Started' logged in your browser console? If not then your event isn't hooked up properly.

Comment: I have no idea what was wrong.  I took your code from the Meteorpad and it worked. Thank you!